# SQL view with substring in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, view, substring, where-clause

I want to put this query into a new view. For your information `dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag` is also a view.

```
SELECT  dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.Angebotsnummer AS AngNr1, 
        dbo.CSDokument.Angebotsnummer AS AngNr2, 
        dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr1, 
        substring(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) AS OAngNr1_SUB10,
        dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr2, 
        substring(dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) AS OAngNr2_SUB10

FROM    dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag INNER JOIN
        dbo.CSDokument ON dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.Angebotsnummer = 
        dbo.CSDokument.Angebotsnummer

WHERE   (LEN(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer) > 10) AND 
        substring(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) 
        =  substring(dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10)
```

But the view builder of management studio always changes the `substring() = substring()` part from the where clause into the `INNER JOIN` part. But with this change I can't save the view `(error- object reference not set to an instance of an object)`. Why is it not possible to use the `substring() = substring()` in the WHERE clause? Or can I reach the goal in another way?

Comment: The query builder designer in ssms is broken. You don't need it to build your queries.

Comment: Did you try to simply create a script like "CREATE VIEW [myschema].[myview] AS SELECT [.....]"? I prefer to script my views without the builder...

Comment: "object reference not set to an instance of an object" isn't an *sql* error. That should clue you into the fact that it's the *tool* that's broken, not the SQL.

Comment: hm ok with CREATE VIEW it worked. Probably there is really a problem with the builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm ok with CREATE VIEW it worked. Probably it is really a problem with the builder. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Just create it with Transact SQL not using management studio create view windows like this:

```
CREATE VIEW AS ViewName
AS
    SELECT  dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.Angebotsnummer AS AngNr1, 
            dbo.CSDokument.Angebotsnummer AS AngNr2, 
            dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr1, 
            substring(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) AS OAngNr1_SUB10,
            dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr2, 
            substring(dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) AS OAngNr2_SUB10

    FROM    dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag INNER JOIN
            dbo.CSDokument ON dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.Angebotsnummer = 
            dbo.CSDokument.Angebotsnummer

    WHERE   (LEN(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer) > 10) AND 
            substring(dbo.TransferAS400Auftrag.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10) 
            =  substring(dbo.CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer, 1, 10);
```